# When I set target in columnDefs dynamically I loose reactivity of radio button in DT table

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, dt

I try to dynamically set target for `columnDefs` in a DT table to hide some column depending of the selection.
Unfortunately, if I change the column to hide, I can no longer access the value of the radio button in the table.

Here is the code for the example (based on [Radio Buttons in DT](https://stackoverflow.com) ) :

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    title = 'Radio buttons in a table',
    selectInput("colHide","Column to hide",choices = c('F','G','H'),multiple =TRUE),
    DT::dataTableOutput('foo'),
    verbatimTextOutput('sel')
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    # table with radio buttons
    m = matrix(
      as.character(1:5), nrow = 12, ncol = 5, byrow = TRUE,
      dimnames = list(month.abb, LETTERS[1:5])
    )
    for (i in seq_len(nrow(m))) {
      m[i, ] = sprintf(
        '<input type="radio" name="%s" value="%s"/>',
        month.abb[i], m[i, ]
      )
    }
    m2<-matrix(
      LETTERS[6:8], nrow = 12, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE,
      dimnames = list(month.abb, LETTERS[6:8])
    )
    m<-cbind(m,m2)
    
    # render table
    output$foo = DT::renderDataTable(
      isolate(m), escape = FALSE, 
      selection = 'none', 
      server = FALSE,
      options = quoToFunction(list(dom = 'Bfrtip', 
                     paging = TRUE, 
                     pageLength = 6,
                     preDrawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node()); }'),
                     drawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node()); } '),
                     # dynamically hide columns
                     columnDefs = list(list(targets = input$colHide, visible = FALSE)),
                     ordering = FALSE)),
      callback = JS("table.rows().every(function(i, tab, row) {
          var $this = $(this.node());
          $this.attr('id', this.data()[0]);
          $this.addClass('shiny-input-radiogroup');
        });
        Shiny.unbindAll(table.table().node());
        Shiny.bindAll(table.table().node());")
    )
    output$sel = renderPrint({
      # print result of radio buttons
      sapply(grep("foo_",names(reactiveValuesToList(input)),value = TRUE,invert = TRUE), function(i) input[[i]])
    })
  }
)
```

In my app, I try the same kind of trick with a `numericInput` and it doesn't work either.
I think I missed something in the `JS` part.